# Case insensitive string comparison

Tags: php, if-statement, case-insensitive

I would like to compare two variables to see if they are the same, but I want this comparison to be case-insensitive.

For example, this would be case sensitive:

```
if($var1 == $var2){
   ...
}
```

But I want this to be case insensitive, how would I approach this?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

This is fairly simple; you just need to call [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) on both variables.

If you need to deal with Unicode or international character sets, you can use [`mb_strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php).

Please note that other answers suggest using [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)—that function *does not handle multibyte characters,* so results for any UTF-8 string will be bogus.

Comment: Thanks, would you also happen to know how i could do a case-insensitive WHERE statement in mysql_query() ?

Comment: In general, I believe MySQL string comparison *is* case-insensitive. That is to say, `'A' = 'a'` is true.  A reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: That's very strange, because that's not what it does for me. I've set collation to latin1_swedish_ci.

Comment: this is example code i'd use: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = '" .$_POST['this']. "'");$check = mysql_num_rows($query);if($check == "0"){}`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on MySQL; you might want to post it as a separate question.

Comment: @Deniz MySQL queries are case sensitive, I use something like this: "ORDER BY LOWER(email), id ASC ";

Comment: using `strtolower()` isn't really "case insensitive". In fact, if you do something like `if($var1 == strtolower($var2))` you are asking if the string is equal to $var2, where $var2 is entirely in lower case. Is it? Maybe not! What if a person enters "MyCouponCode" into the text field, where the coupon code is "MYCOUPONCODE"? The comparison would fail.

Comment: You'd typically use `strtolower()` on both strings to be compared.

Comment: Note that you may encounter charset issues with this method (e.g. if you use some weird UTF-8 characters)
In that case, use `mb_strtolower()` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not so simple: in Unicode, the lower case variant's upper case char may not be the same, as you've started with – and same for the other way around. I.e. you have to compare with mb_strtolower() AND with mb_strttoupper().

Comment: @Beat you doubled the 't' in `mb_strtoupper()` (not copy/paste friendly :))

Comment: @robotik I can't edit a comment, but you can copy from my answer, it's correct there ;)

Comment: Thank you for this nice and good answer. Sometimes, it can be so easy.

Answer (score 77):

[`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) returns 0 if the strings are the same (apart from case variations) so you can use:

```
if (strcasecmp($var1, $var2) == 0) {
}
```

Comment: Just remember to test for == 0; this is counter-intuitive as it's very tempting to write "if (strcasecmp($var1, $var2)) { ..." but in this case 0 means equal rather than false-notequal as is often the case.

Comment: `strcasecmp()` does not deal with multibyte characters, so it can't cope with Unicode.

Answer (score 24):

If your string is in a single byte encoding, it's simple:

```
if(strtolower($var1) === strtolower($var2))
```

If your string is UTF-8, you have to consider the complexity of Unicode: to-lower-case and to-upper-case are not bijective functions, i.e. if you have a lower case character, transform it to upper case, and transform it back to lower case, you may not end up with the same code point (and the same holds true if you start with an upper case character).

E.g.

- "İ" (`Latin Capital Letter I with Dot Above, U+0130`) is an upper case character, with "i" (`Latin Small Letter I, U+0069`) as its lower case variant – and "i"'s upper case variant is "I" (`Latin Capital Letter I, U+0049`).
- "ı" (`Latin Small Letter Dotless I, U+0131`) is a lower case character, with "I" (`Latin Capital Letter I, U+0049`) as its upper case variant – and "I"'s lower case variant is "i" (`Latin Small Letter I, U+0069`)

So `mb_strtolower('ı') === mb_strtolower('i')` returns false, even though they have the same upper case character. If you really want a case-insensitive string comparison function, you have to compare to upper case AND the lower case version:

```
if(mb_strtolower($string1) === mb_strtolower($string2)
  || mb_strtoupper($string1) === mb_strtoupper($string2))
```

I've run a query against the Unicode database from https://codepoints.net (https://dumps.codepoints.net) and I've found 180 code point for which I found a different character when taking a lower case characters's upper case's lower case, and 8 code point for which I found a different character when taking an upper case characters's lower case's upper case

**But it gets worse**: the same grapheme cluster seen by the user, may have multiple ways of encoding it: "ä" may be represented as `Latin Small Letter a with Diaeresis (U+00E4)` or as `Latin Small Letter A (U+0061)` and `Combining Diaeresis (U+0308)` – and if you compare them at a byte level, this won't return true!

But there is a solution for this in Unicode: [**Normalization**](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)! There are four different forms: NFC, NFD, NFKC, NFKD. For string comparison, NFC and NFD are equivalent and NFKC and NFKD are equivalent. I'd take NFKC as it is shorter than NFKD, and "ﬀ" (`Latin Small Ligature ff, U+FB00`) will be transformed to two normal "f" (but 2⁵ will also be expanded to 25…).

The resulting function becomes:

```
function mb_is_string_equal_ci($string1, $string2) {
    $string1_normalized = Normalizer::normalize($string1, Normalizer::FORM_KC);
    $string2_normalized = Normalizer::normalize($string2, Normalizer::FORM_KC);
    return mb_strtolower($string1_normalized) === mb_strtolower($string2_normalized)
            || mb_strtoupper($string1_normalized) === mb_strtoupper($string2_normalized);
}
```

Please note:

- you need the [intl](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) package for the [Normalizer](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php)
- you should optimize this function by first checking if they're just equal^^
- you may want to use NFC instead of NFKC, because NFKC removes too many formatting distinctions for your taste
- you have to decide for yourself, if you really need all this complexity or if you prefer a simpler variant of this function

Answer (score 2):

```
if(strtolower($var1) == strtolower($var2)){
}
```

Comment: Although I understand this technique and it is rather basic, this is not a generous or explained answer.  When new researchers see old code-only answers, they will start to think that that is a perfectly acceptable answer on Stackoverflow.  Please role model better posting behavior with the intent to educate instead of dumping a solution and wallking away.

Answer (score 1):

```php
// to return boolean "are input strings equal?"
function mb_strcasecmp($s1,$s2): bool {
  return 0 === mb_stripos($s1,$s2) && 0 === mb_stripos($s2,$s1);
}
```

This version supports multibyte characters but doesn't require the [intl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) package.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
if(strtolower($var1) == strtolower($var2)){
}
```