# Yii2 compare email without case sensitive

Tags: validation, yii2, compare

I use the simple compare validation rule offered by Yii2 like this:

```
[confirm_email', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'email', 'message'=>"Emails don't match"],
```

The problem is that this rule compares two emails 100% including Case Sensitive which means **email@test.com** and **email@Test.com** will generate validation error.

Is there a way to remove this Case Sensitive comparison from this rule?

Answer (score 2):

`strcasecmp` *does not handle multibyte characters*, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473542/case-insensitive-string-comparison)

suggestion is to use [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

you might also be interested in [yii's input filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#filter), to transform input to lowercase, like this:

```
[
    // both email fields tolower
    [['email', 'confirm_email'], 'filter', 'filter' => 'strtolower'],

    // normalize "phone" input
    ['phone', 'filter', 'filter' => function ($value) {
        // normalize phone input here
        return $value;
    }], ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom validation if you want.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // an inline validator defined as the model method validateEmail()
        ['email', 'validateEmail'],
    ];
}

public function validateEmail($attribute, $params)
{
    if (strcasecmp($this->attribute, $this->confirm_email) == 0) {
         $this->addError($attribute, 'Username should only contain alphabets');
    }
}
```

It will compare emails with binary safe case-insensitive.