# IF stament return me FALSE when should return TRUE

Tags: php, if-statement

Question:

```
    
    if ("sometext" == "SOMEtext") {
        echo "TRUE";
    } else {
        echo "FALSE";
    }
```

It is return me *FALSE*, when I use double equal.
The only diference are the capital leters...
This if should return *TRUE* ????

Comment: String comparisons are case sensitive.  Your assumption is incorrect.  Check out this question for a solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473542/case-insensitive-string-comparison

Comment: `==` will only change the type if the two operands of that operator are not of the same type, but in your case both operands are a string. When comparing the two strings here, the "s" character is a different character than "S", just like it is different to "š" or whatever variant you try. This means that both strings are not equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtolower("somestring")` in order to compare 2 strings without account for case sensitivity